# locationManager.isProviderEnabled is not working with Genymortion emulator

Tags: java, android, gps

I am new to JAVA and I have to create an app that plot a route between where I am (found by GPS) and some pre-specified destination. I followed online tutorials such as http://androidexample.com/GPS_Basic__-__Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=68&aaid=93 to learn how to read my own location.

I want my app to act differently when the GPS is turned on and off. To read the GPS status I used an LocationManager object as line below:

```
    boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

I can manually turn the GPS off in Genymortion emulator by right clicking the GPS tab. The picture below shows how I turned on the GPS.
[image]

However, my app always say either isGPSEnabled = true all the time or isGPSEnabled = false all the time even though I change the GPS status. Can anyone tells me what I am missing? I attached most of my code below if that helps.

```
public class MapDisplayActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private MapDisplayFragment fragment;
    private DrawerLayout sideDrawerMenu;
    private ListView sideDrawerMenuList;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private boolean isGPSEnabled;

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "MapDisplayActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.side_drawer_menu);

        // some codes come here...

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled =  locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        if (isGPSEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    5000,   // 5 sec
                    10, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            String str = "Latitude: " + 
            location.getLatitude() 
            + "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            gpsLatlon = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned on ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    // ~~~~~~~~~~ to imeplement LocationListener ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    private class SideDrawerClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
// some more methods definitions....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to set the `isGPSEnabled` flag in the callbacks:

```
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
           isGPSEnabled = false;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
           isGPSEnabled = true;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned on ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

One thing to note is that these callbacks will only be called if you currently have the Activity registered as a location listener.
So, as you have it now, only the `onProviderDisabled()` callback will be called if the Activity starts with GPS on and then GPS is disabled with the Activity still running.

One way to go would be to register for `NETWORK_PROVIDER` callbacks when GPS is disabled.

That way you would still have a location listener registered, and you would get the `onProviderEnabled()` callback for GPS. At that point you could unregister for NETWORK callbacks and register for GPS callbacks.

Comment: I added the if statements on those methods but isGPSEnabled = true; when it should be false....

Comment: @ThePrincess, are you seeing the Toast messages when you enable and disable GPS?

Comment: I am seeing that isGPSEnabled=true both when i enable and disable GPS